# Can a finite collection of stick-breaking weights be viewed as a sample from a finite Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $w$ be a finite collection of stick breaking weights, i.e.
$$ w = (w_k)_{k=1}^K $$
formed by
$$ w_k = w'_k \prod_{j<k} (1-w'_j) $$
where
$$ w'_k \sim \text{Beta}(u_k, v_k) \quad \text{ for } k=1,..,K-1$$
and
$$ w'_K = 1$$

Can we see $w$ as a sample from a finite dimensional Dirichlet distribution?  If so, what are the parameters of the Dirichlet?

Comment: Can you take us through your own thought process?

Comment: See p. 585 here: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/BDA3.pdf.

Comment: Thanks - helpful reference!   My thought process: I am trying to understand how variational approximations to the DP-type models (e.g., section 3 of http://proceedings.mlr.press/v15/wang11a/wang11a.pdf) can place variational distributions on stick proportions that allow (u_k, v_k) to freely vary.   The Gelman reference suggests there may be a constraint of the form $v_k = \sum_{j=k+1}^K u_j$.  This is almost satisfied by the variational update equations (e.g. see (15) and (16) of Wong et al.), but (1) scalars are added  and (2) this constraint falls out of optimization rather than assumption

Comment: So I believe there may be a more general scheme for a stick-breaking representation of a Dirichlet than what is mentioned by Gelman, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I'm not sure I can offer you more help at the moment. Let's hope for some input.

Comment: For instance, in the Wang et al. paper, what is the distribution on $\beta$ (the weights) implied by the provided distribution on $\beta'$ (the stick-breaking proportions)?  I cannot answer based on the Gelman scheme, because the construction seems to fall outside of its purview (as per the observations above).